# How to track failed login attempts during 10 sec

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, settimeout

So I'm doing a simple login form with a submit button.
So idea is to track the failed attempts when a user tries to log in.
If the user failed 5 attempts then submit button will be disabled for 30sec.
So far it's pretty simple, but I'm trying to implement that button will be disabled only if those 5 attempts were during the 10sec. So I'm stacked here... Hope for your help folks!

This is what I got so far

```
const [login, setLogin] = useState<string>('')
const [error, setError] = useState<string>('')
const [attempts, setAttempts] = useState<number>(0)

useEffect(()=>{
    if(attempts===5){
        setTimeout(()=>{
            setAttempts(0)
        },1000)
    }
},[attempts])   

const onChangeHandler = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setLogin(e.target.value)
}

const useHandler = () => {
    setAttempts(prevState => prevState + 1)
    if (login === 'valid') {
        axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/anon').then(res => console.log(res.data))
        setError('')
        setAttempts(0)
    } else if (login !== 'valid') {
        if (attempts >= 0 && attempts < 5) {
            setError('unsuccessful login attempt')
        }
    }
}
```

and my return here is my return

```
 <div className="App">
        <div className={'loginBlock'}>
            <div>
                <input name={'login'} value={login} type="text"
                   onChange={onChangeHandler}/>
                <button disabled={attempts === 5} onClick={useHandler}>submit</button>
            </div>
            <div style={{color: 'red'}}>{error}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It's _absolutely useless_ to do this in a client-side script. Nobody does brute force login attempts by hand, and bots aren't going to be stopped by anything you do in JavaScript. You must add this timeout on the server side instead.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, but a got this problem during the interview. So there should be some way to solve it

Comment: Maybe it was a trick question ;)